# Calling web api with client certificate from another web api

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api

Scenario: User talks with WebApi called 'Gateway' by angularjs client. 'Gateway' is like a facade or a proxy, so all requests from User to 'Gateway' will be forwarded to another WebApis.

Security details: 'Gateway' WebApi and all others WebApis are placed in IIS with HTTPS binding and SSL client certificate option is 'Accept'. So, user will provide valid client certificate to IIS and after verification, request will be handled by WebApi.

The problem: when 'Gateway' WebApi receives a request, client certificate is presented in Request object. Then I just forward this request using HttpClient to another WebApi. But when another WebApi endpoint receives a request, there is not client certificate attached any more.

Below is a code snipped of request forwarding:

```
var request = Request; // income request from angularjs

var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(request.GetClientCertificate()); // setting up client certificate from user's request
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    request.RequestUri = *chaning request address here*;
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

Note: If I try to go directly to the another WebApi, client certificate is presented as expected. If I try to go via 'Gateway', client certificate is presented as well in 'Gateway' request, but after it's successfully attached and request is sent, another WebApi does not receive any certificate attached.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Does "another WebApi" need to get the certificate which the end-user had (for identification) at "Gateway"?  Or would it be okay to simply authenticate the user at "Gateway" and Gateway used a service account to authenticate "Gateway" to "another WebApi"?

Comment: Basically, I have separate web api endpoint, which is responsible for dealing with client certificates. And it will be preferable to leave gateway web api only dealing with forwarding requests and nothing else. Thank you

Comment: Okay.  It matters, because there are two completely different answers to your question and it depends on whether you need to pass the authentication through to the next server.

Answer (score 0):

On your gateway server, you need to import an authentication key onto the "machine" certificate store  (MMC.exe, add snap-in "Certificates", Computer account", Certficates-Personal-Certificates, import).
Grant permissions (for the auth cert) to the account which your IIS pool is using. (right-click the cert, All-Tasks, Manage private keys. Add, Advanced, Locations=[machine-name], find now, (probably) Network Service, Read).

In your web.config (on your gateway server), check your `system.serviceModel` / `behaviors` / `endpointBehaviors` / `behavior` / `clientCredentials` / `clientCertificate`. Make sure the attribute: `storeLoction`="LocalMachine", to use the cert from the machine key store.

Comment: There will be many clients with many different client certificates, each of which contains user identity details. So, just to clarify, it's not possible to forward request with attached client certificate to another web api from gateway without storing these all possible incoming certificates on gateway mmc storage?

Comment: That is why I asked my question earlier.  It is possible to pass the client credentials through to the API server, but it is a totally different answer and configs.

Comment: tgolisch, could you please describe possible solution since I haven't had a success yet?

Comment: I haven't worked out a demo for the other solution, but I'm fairly certain that it involves a Kerberos trust between the two servers, and impersonation on the gateway server.